# AngularJS toaster close button not visible

Tags: angularjs, notifications

I am using AngularJS Toaster in my application for getting dynamic notifications.Present I am getting the notifications but close button is not visible. This is my code

```
 var message = "Welcome..";
        $scope.popToaster = function(){
            toaster.pop('success', "Alert", message);
}
```

HTML :

```
 <toaster-container toaster-options="{'close-button': true}"></toaster-container>
```

Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Could you please create a JSFiddle? It is hard to tell from your snippet what's actually your problem. Also, what version of Toaster do you use?

Comment: I am using  Toaster 0.3. [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/boa0Ih303Z3gs7N5zplV?p=preview) here.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you are using version 0.3 of AngularJS-Toaster I suggest to use the latest version or at least 0.4.7. The close button was added above 0.4.6 as you can see [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-toaster/0.4.7/toaster.js) in the directive template. Another advantage is that you can use functions like `success` or `error` on the `toaster` service itself. Here is a small example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <toaster-container toaster-options="{'close-button':true}"></toaster-container>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <button type="button" ng-click="displayToaster()">Toaster</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the script file:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["toaster"]);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http, toaster) {
    $scope.displayToaster = function () {
        toaster.success("Welcome...");
    };
});
```

So please use the latest version 0.4.13 from the official [git repository](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster).